# Baffling incident of number format exception

Tags: java

I am trying to parse some integers in loop. Some of them are throwing `NumberFormatException` weirdly because it shows error :-

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "600"

The line that throws error :-

```
    closingPoints += Integer.parseInt(tokens[i + 1]);
```

Comment: If you look closer at the string when you're running your code, you might find it has weird or unprintable characters in it. Just because it looks like `600` to you, doesn't mean it looks like `600` to a computer.

Answer (score 3):

You have non-printable / Non-ASCII characters on your String.
You can try to remove them using a regular expression. For example

```
closingPoints += Integer.parseInt(tokens[i + 1].replaceAll( "[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "" ));
```

What the above regex does is to replace all characters that are not (^) between the hexadecimal range of 00-7F (0-127) which is the range of ASCII characters. If a character on that range is found, it replaces it with empty String.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you do not have:

- spaces
- invisible control characters
- the 0 (zero) is not an O (Oh)
- unicode characters